# Why rotation of three.js global var camera is not changing while position is?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to move the camera and rotate it in it's own axis. While position change is working fine, rotation doesn't work.

Here is part of my source:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100000);

function camera2() {
    this.main = function () {
        var camPos = spline.getPoint(camPosIndex / 1000);
        camera.position.x = camPos.x;
        camera.position.y = camPos.y;
        camera.position.z = camPos.z;
        camera.rotation.z += 0.01;    // that doesn't work !!!
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 20000));
    }
}

function renderScene() {
    fx[i]["fx"].main();    // call of camera2.main()
    requestAnimationFrame(renderScene);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

When I'm calling `camera.rotation.z += 0.01` in `renderScene()`, it's working, but it seems referring to another camera (?). I have only one global `var camera`, and position works inside `main()`, but rotation doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling the camera to `lookAt()` a particular point. That will override any camera rotation you're manually trying to set.

Comment: Shit. It's working when I don't call LookAt! Thanks. But why?

Comment: I suppose LookAt is overriding camera position and rotation properties. Thank you again!

Comment: Imagine you can fly and you are the camera. Fly to an arbitrary position in the air and turn and look at the moon. You can turn and look at the moon while hanging at the same position in the air, by just rotating your body + head in the direction of the moon. It should be the same with the camera.